# Dockerhub automated builds with multiple private repos

Tags: git, github, go, docker, dockerhub

Is there a way to connect to multiple private git repos during an automated dockerhub build? We are building golang apps and need to 'go get' other private repos as part of our build and at the moment they fail as docker can't connect to them, only the target private repo.

The main repo is fine as the deploy key is installed via Dockerhub, but any subsequent private repo imports fail.

One way around this I can see, is to build the image locally, "docker push" it to dockerhub and then pull it down on the deploy side which defeats the purpose of dockerhub and the automated build system. The other is to bake ssh keys into the base image which is not a great idea.

Does anyone have a solution to this that doesn't involve baking ssh keys into images or building locally?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure: Even go mobile will curl its dependencies first, then build itself in the Dockerfile (https://github.com/golang/mobile/blob/master/Dockerfile), as mentioned in https://deferpanic.com/blog/logging-panics-in-golang-on-android/.

Comment: You could do the build on some kind of CI server, such as CircleCI. I've had a good experience building images on their service and pushing to Docker Hub. I suppose it could be possible to integrate multiple repos, but I've never tried.

Answer (score 1):

**single ssh-key**

If you have only one `ssh-key`, then adding it to the `root` ssh-path in the Docker container (`/root/.ssh/id_rsa`) should be enough to successfully pulling your repos. Depends where your private-repos are, you should probably add some other configs to the `.ssh`.

**multiple ssh-keys**

If you have differents `ssh-keys` I suggest you to create a personal token for all your repos. So you can resolve easily the problem. You should update the `git`-url before getting:

[ taken from here: https://gist.github.com/shurcooL/6927554 ]

```
git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

With this change, you should be able to build successfully your docker-container.

---

Using a `vendor`-tool can help you solving this. From `go1.5` the vendoring feature is at disposal. We are using [Glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) and it stores the references only (not the wholes projects).

Comment: Is this secure? Would your ssh key be leaked?

Comment: @AleksandarJovanovic if someone can get access to the docker container yes, the potential attacker can steal your ssh keys. This depends about your security layer that you add on the container and on the host "hosting" the container(s). To decrease the chance to steal of ssh keys, you can remove them when the container starts